# Python - IndexError: list index out of range even though checking if empty

Tags: python, del, index-error

I'm getting the IndexError: list index out of range on the following line of code:

```
if tweetSplit[i] != "":
```

in my code:

```
tweetSplit = tweet.split(' ') 

for i in range(len(tweetSplit)):
    #print (i)
    if not tweetSplit:
        break
    if tweetSplit[i] != "":
         #print (tweetSplit[i])
         #print (tweetSplit[i][:1])
        if tweetSplit[i][:1] == '@':
            del tweetSplit[i]
```

I thought by checking if tweetSplit is empty using "if not tweetSplit" I wouldn't run into the out of range error. 
Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parseTweets.py", line 55, in <module>
     if tweetSplit[i] != "":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please show us the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test doesn't really do much good.

Sure `if not tweetsplit:` checks if `tweetsplit` is empty. But it doesn't check if `tweetsplit` is at least `i+1` elements long.

And, because you're deleting from `tweetsplit` in the middle of the loop, if you delete even one element, then, by the end, it will be shorter than `i+1`, and raise an `IndexError`.

This is one of the reasons you should never delete or insert in the middle of looping over any collection. (But not the only one—for example, when you delete element `i`, that moves all the others up one slot, and then you check the new element `i+1`, which was originally `i+2`… which means you missed one.)

---

If you want to build a collection of all tweets that match some rule, it's much easier to do that by building a new list:

```
goodTweets = []
for tweet in tweetSplit:
    if tweet[:1] != '@':
        goodTweets.append(tweet)
```

Or:

```
goodTweets = [tweet for tweet in tweetSplit if tweet[:1] != '@']
```

---

If you really do need to mutate `tweetSplit` for some reason, there are tricks you can use, but they're all a bit ugly.

Build a new list, then change `tweetSplit` into that list:

```
tweetSplit[:] = [tweet for tweet in tweetSplit if tweet[:1] != '@']
```

Or, do it without building the new list explicitly:

```
tweetSplit[:] = (tweet for tweet in tweetSplit if tweet[:1] != '@')
```

Or iterate backward. While `len(tweetSplit)` may change as you delete, 0 never does. (And while the positions of everything from `i:` may change, the positions of `:i` never do.)

```
for i in range(len(tweetSplit))[::-1]:
    if tweetSplit[i][:1] == '@':
        del tweetSplit[i]
```

However, if you're trying to do this in-place as a performance optimization, all of these are usually slower. The only thing likely to be faster is something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(tweetSplit):
    if tweetSplit[i][:1] == '@':
        tweetSplit[i] = tweetSplit[-1]
        tweetSplit.pop()
    else:
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `IndexError` because of this:

`del tweetSplit[i]`

What happens is that you are deleting elements inside `tweetSplit`. This causes `tweetSplit` to have a reduced length.

To solve this, don't delete any element from `tweetSplit`. Just traverse through the list. No need to delete any element.

If you don't need to handle any indexes, you just use a for-each loop in Python.

```
for tweet in tweetSplit:
    if tweet != "" and tweet[:1] == '@':
        # Do something but don't delete any tweet from tweetSplit.
```

Comment: The purpose of my assignment is to delete words beginning with '@' from the string however

Comment: @user1098432, in that case, then just place any words not beginning with '@' in another list.

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't sure that tweetSplit[i] will be in scope at this point, you can instead use something like:

```
if isinstance(tweetSplit[i], str):
```

This will return a boolean if the value of tweetSplit[i] is of type string.

With the way you are deleting values from the tweetSplit array though, you will likely run into issues with the way you are indexing.